CP Optimizer: Subtracting time-dependent value from cumul Function with minValue 0
in a CP model (simplified version of Laborie et al. 2018) I have a cumulFunction rUsage indicating the material demand along time, derived by the demand rate dmdR of a present interval variable:
dvar interval mode[m in Modes] optional size m.pt;
cumulFunction rUsage = sum(m in Modes) pulse (mode[m], m.dmdR)

In my example, the following material demand results:
rUsage: stepwise{0 -> 0, 5 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 6 -> 3}

To serve that material demand, material of type A should be used first before material type B is used.
The given amount of material A along time is provided by supplyA:
int supplyA[h in 1..3] = [5, 100, 5];

My question is how to derive the remaining demand for material B, i.e. to get
bUsage: stepwise{0 -> 2, 1 -> 3}

In other words: how to subtract a time-dependent parameter from cumul Function while ensuring that resulting function is non-negative (e.g. at time 2 in given example)?
I tried to model the consumption of material A by additional interval variables and a corresponding cumulFunction. However, I could not model the partly consumption of A (in periods with a supply higher than total material demand).
Thanks in advance!

For the record, a duplicate and a discussion can be found here:
https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/discussion/cp-optimizer-subtracting-time-dependent-value-from-cumul-function-with-minvalue-0#bm339bc2dd-e890-4892-ab52-0191e5614233
And the final answer was:


using CP;
range horizon = 0..2;

tuple Mode { key int id; int pt; int dmdR; };
{Mode} Modes = {<1,1,5>, <2,1,4>, <3,1,6>} ;

int capacityA [horizon] = [3, 100, 5];
int capacityB [horizon] = [5, 5, 5];

dvar interval mode[m in Modes] size m.pt;
cumulFunction levelR = sum(m in Modes) pulse(mode[m], m.dmdR);
cumulFunction supplyA = sum(h in horizon) pulse(h, h+1, capacityA[h]);
dvar interval additionalSupplyB[h in horizon] optional in h..h+1;
cumulFunction supplyB = sum(h in horizon) pulse(additionalSupplyB[h], 1, capacityB[h]);
cumulFunction totalSupply = supplyA + supplyB;
dvar sequence line in all(m in Modes) mode[m];

minimize staticLex(max(m in Modes) endOf(mode[m]), sum(h in horizon) heightAtStart(additionalSupplyB[h], supplyB, 0));
subject to { 
  noOverlap(line);
  totalSupply - levelR >= 0;
}

execute{
  writeln("----");
  writeln("Total Resource Usage: ", levelR);
  writeln("----");
  writeln("B Usage: ", supplyB);
}



